# Show image and video in the same view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimage

So far I have been using `UIImageView` with [Hankee](https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift) library to display images from URL, and this player to display videos from URL: https://github.com/piemonte/Player

But is there any library or anything that support playing both images and mp4 videos in the same controller?

Answer (score 0):

UIImageView and the Player library you linked in can easily coexist.

```
// First we add the video player
self.player = Player()
self.player.delegate = self
self.player.view.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 200, height: 200) // We set where we want the video player to appear

self.addChildViewController(self.player)
self.view.addSubview(self.player.view)
self.player.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

// Now we add the image
let image = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 250, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100)) // We set where we want to image view to appear
self.view.addSubiew(image)
```

You just need to the video player and UIImageView's frame position and sizes.

In your example, you set it to full screen. So it blocked everything.

Comment: But the thing is that I have a array of URL's. The URL can have .png or .mp4 extension - so if the file is png, it load imageView fullscreen, and if file is .mp4, it load video fullscreen.

Comment: Just simply conduct a check manually and place the according view on the screen